# Where do I find all the Angular Material framework's classes?

Tags: angular-material

Angular Material's docs is very well looking and clear as well.

But there are several examples where some classes are used (e.g. md-colored in https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.button/directive/mdButton ).
Where do I find them?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I recommend you set up yr dependencies using bower.
Instructions here :  https://github.com/angular/material#bower

And once you do so, inside yr bower_components folder you have everything. You can go and read documentation and you will find whole css and js as well.

```
 bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css
```

Comment: thank you nitin. I will try it asap (same for the other answer of yours)